# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 - Custom Homepage blocks with webparts

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, 2013

I'm basically working on an new website which is based on sharepoint foudation 2013. I've done the design and now i'm on development phase. After good time searching around in code i could not find a way to create the announcement block to look like i want. There are around 5 bloks on homepage which looks pretty similar,just different features.

I can't use image for preview as i'm new here, but i will try to explain.
Well as you know if you insert an webpart for example Announcements, it's show the title of the webpart, and bellow the announcements + read more button in case if you want to see more. Actually i want to insert an image in the left side and to push all the content to the right side.
I was trying to do that in the homepage code where is the webpart code inserted but i've got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to fix that issue aswell. By creating the blocks in the home.aspx page and inserting the webpart code in different divs. Well problem sovled.

Thank you.